# How to convert time in string UTC time format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.MMMMMMSUTC to timestamp format and DDDDDDDDHHMMSS.MMMMMM:000 to interval format in C?

Tags: c, datetime

By running the command

```
wmic OS Get LastBootUpTime
```

I get time in string UTC time format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.MMMMMMSUTC`.
If string is known to be timestamp, then convert it to timestamp format:

```
typedef struct _Timestamp
{
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int hour;
    unsigned int minute;
    unsigned int second;
    unsigned int microseconds;
    signed int utc;
}
Timestamp;
```

Eg: Time: 20210324111750.500000+330

if **isTimestamp = true**.

```
Timestamp.year = 2021
Timestamp.month = 03
Timestamp.day = 24
Timestamp.hour = 11
Timestamp.minute = 17
Timestamp.second = 50
Timestamp.microseconds = 500000
Timestamp.utc = +330
```

If it is known to be in interval, convert string from `DDDDDDDDHHMMSS.MMMMMM:000` format to interval format:

```
typedef struct _Interval
{
    unsigned int days;
    unsigned int hours;
    unsigned int minutes;
    unsigned int seconds;
    unsigned int microseconds;
    unsigned int __padding1;
    unsigned int __padding2;
    unsigned int __padding3;
}
Interval;
```

Eg: Time: 00000324111750.500000:000

if **isTimestamp = false**.

```
Interval.days = 324
Interval.hours = 11
Interval.minutes = 17
Interval.seconds = 50
Interval.microseconds = 500000
Interval.__padding1 = 0
Interval.__padding2 = 0
Interval.__padding3 = 0
```

Manually parsing the string seems to be a very long approach.

Can someone suggest C inbuilt functions to achieve this. or If there are functions readily available to convert `char *` to the above time formats.

Comment: "Manually parsing the string seems to be a very long approach" Well, C has function to convert strings to intergers (e.g. strtoul) so it's not that difficult to implement

Comment: You could use `sscanf`.